# How can I log out idle users?

Tags: users, kiosk

I have some kiosk PCs that pretty much work like the Ubuntu guest session. The kiosk users home has a union filesystem mounted on top of it so the can't change anything but can still save files while working at the machine (and take them with them using a USB key).

Users sometimes leave the stations with private stuff still on the desktop. Because of that I want them logged out after - say - 10 minutes of inactivity (the union file system will be emptied on logout).

Any ideas if there is an existing solution (autolog only logs the user out of active terminal sessions).

Comment: Read up on these, find which one suits you best. * Ubuntu autolog. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/man8/autolog.8.html
* Ubuntu timeouts. /etc/timeouts. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/timeouts.5.html
* Ubuntu timeoutd. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man8/timeoutd.8.html
* With timeoutd, you can also limit what hours a user or tty can log in, set limit on minutes of use, and minutes of idle time. * And a [Google search for you](https://www.google.com/search?rls=ig&biw=973&bih=581&site=webhp&q=ubuntu%20how%20to%20log%20out%20idle%20users&oq=ubuntu%20how%

Comment: As I mentioned, autolog doesn't work. Neither does timeoutd because both rely on */etc/run/utmp*. For utmp the X session is active *all the time* so it will never be seen as idle. timeouts is just the configuration file of timeoutd. Both work nice for terminal-only applications but not for desktop sessions.

Comment: So killing the tty is not enough? You need something to kill the Xsession?

Comment: If I do `who|grep localhost:` every line that contains `localhost:` I think is an Xwindow. That might help you at least find the Xwindow ttys.

Comment: @Bulrush: I can only repeat what I wrote above. For the reasons stated */var/run/utmp* is not suitable to detect if an X user is idle. autolog and timeoutd would work for SSH users, but not for xsession users.

Comment: What I was trying to say was, someone might have to write a script to 1) Find all X windows, 2) Find which X windows are idle, and 3) Kill the idle X windows that have been idle too long. My code was for step 1.

Comment: I don't want to check for idle windows and kill them. I want to see if the user is idle (no mouse/keyboard activity) and if so, log the user out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Frustrated with `autolog`, I wrote my own script too. It's on [Github](https://github.com/murukeshm/scratchpad/tree/master/linux/idlekiller).

- It's general enough for multiple users, on X sessions and TTYs.
- I have included an Upstart job, assuming that the script is placed at `/usr/bin/idlekiller`

To set it up:

```
sudo apt-get install xprintidle
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/murukeshm/scratchpad/master/linux/idlekiller/idlekiller.conf -O /etc/init/idlekiller.conf
sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/murukeshm/scratchpad/master/linux/idlekiller/idlekiller -O /usr/bin/idlekiller
sudo service idlekiller start
```

Comment: Way better than my hacked together thing, thanks!

Comment: @mniess thanks. I wondered whether I should post it, since for the case of a single-user kiosk, your solution is enough.

Comment: I'll use my own thing for sure, but it's always good to have a more general solution.

Comment: @muru hey what do I have to end and how in your scripts to make it auto logout idle users exactly after 10 mins and warn them after 9 mins but before 1 min of auto logout, that they will be logged out if session stays idle.

Comment: @muru I'm no coder or developer, but I just used your code as is and it works well. thanks for that & please accept my apologies for bad english and explanations.

Comment: @Rishee Try setting `IDLE=540` (9 minutes in seconds), `TIMEOUT=8m` (or something less than `9m`), `GRACE=1m`. The IDLE is 9 minutes, so that the grace period + IDLE = 10 minutes.

Comment: @muru Thanks Muru. I am getting an error after starting the service:

Comment: root@ossec-server:~# service idle-killer restart
stop: Unknown instance: 
start: Job failed to start
root@ossec-server:~#

Comment: Syslog says:

http://pastebin.com/1Qq0q8bE

Comment: @ any idea how to resolve this

Comment: @muru below are the contents of file and installation procedure i followed:http://pastebin.com/x9EKiY8X

Comment: @Rishee I'd changed filenames in the Github code and forgot to update here. Rename `idle-killer.sh` to `idlekiller` (no extension) and `idle-killer.conf` to `idlekiller.conf`.

Comment: @muru Hey thanks for the tips. now service starts without any error and it also kills the idle bash user, but it is not killing the idle ssh user who enters the bash through remote systems. do you have a way we can also cover such users in it? please help it is required for PCI - DSS compliance.

Comment: @Rishee I didn't consider SSH users in this since SSH itself has an option called `ClientAliveInterval` for this.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote my own script to do this. There is a tool called *xprintidle* that gives you the idle time of an xsession. You need to install it first

```bsh
sudo apt-get install xprintidle
```

Then create the script, for example in */root/bin/idle_check.sh*:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

DISPLAY=:0
TIMEOUT=600000 # 10min = 10 * 60 * 1000

if [ $(xprintidle) -gt $TIMEOUT ]; then
    notify-send -t 60000 -i system-shutdown-panel-restart -u critical "WARNING" \
        "This machine looks idle and will be logged out in 60s.\nTo prevent this, move the mouse!"
    sleep 60;
    if [ $(xprintidle) -gt $TIMEOUT ]; then
        pkill -u matthias
    fi
fi
```

I opened roots crontab to make it check every minute

```bsh
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

and have it look like this

```bsh
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11
*/1 * * * *   /root/bin/check_idle.sh > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Works like a charm.